# Why will my std::map not accept its key as an index via its subscript operator?

Tags: visual-c++, stl, hashmap

My code originally looked something like this:

```
int SomeObject::operator[]( const string& key ) const
{
    return ( *m_Map )[ key ];
}

int SomeObject::operator()( const string& key ) const
{
    return ( *m_Map2 )[ key ];
}
```

Both of these maps had the following signature:

`std::map< std::string, int >`

And then I read something about STL containers really having no need for explicit heap allocation ( i.e. `std::map< ... >* map = new std::map< ... >` ), which is what I was doing.

As soon as I change the maps to being stack allocated and remove the pointer dereferences so that it looks like this:

```
int SomeObject::operator[]( const string& key ) const
{
    return m_Map[ key ];
}

int SomeObject::operator()( const string& key ) const
{
    return m_Map2[ key ];
}
```

The compiler complains with the following error ( for both maps ):

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Wat.

Comment: Can you show _exactly_ how `m_Map` and `m_Map2` are declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you've marked the functions as `const` and `operator[]()` on `std::map` modifies the map (if the key is not in the map, an element is added with a default value).

You could get away with this when using the pointer because the `const` only applied to the member pointer, not to the object the pointer referred to.

Something like the following should get around the `const` problem:

```
int SomeObject::operator[]( const string& key ) const
{
    std::map<string,int>::const_iterator it(m_Map.find(key));

    if (it == m_Map.end()) {
        throw /* something */;
    }

    return it->second;
}
```